# export my drag-n-drop code from toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have collected some code snippets that i dropped in my visual studio 2008 toolbox > General Tab.

Is there a way to export those snippets and import it into Visual Studio 2008 on Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to copy the snippet directory from old VS and paste it in new VS? You can see a directory path by entering into Code snippet manager (*Tools -> Code snippets manager*). There is a import button also.